# is it possible to move the Thermal Measurer in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm Playing Don't Starve and I have built up my base, but exploring I have found the Thermal Measurer.

My question:
Is there any way to move it to my base?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to move the Thermal Measurer to your base directly.

The closest you can get is to use a Hammer or Deconstruction Staff to break the Thermal Measurer into its components, then rebuild it in your base. The Staff is harder to get, but returns all of the materials; the Hammer destroys half of the materials of anything it deconstructs.

Building the Thermal Measurer requires 2 boards, 2 gold, and access to a Science Machine, so it it's fairly easy to build once you have a Science Machine.